# White screen shown when pushing view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Pushing a view controller:

```
func showChatLogForTrainer(trainer: Trainers) {
    let chatLogVC = ChatLogVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogVC, animated: true)
}
```

But when running the app, it shows a white screen before showing the view controller. It didn't used to do this.. but I haven't touched how the view is shown so not sure why it's doing it now.

[image]

The `viewDidLoad` in `ChatLogVC`;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 38/255, blue: 45/255, alpha: 1);
    self.collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
    self.collectionView?.indicatorStyle = .white
    self.collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
}
```

Comment: You will have to post code of the `ChatLogVC` so that we know what is happening in its `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Rikh have added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it is a bug with the simulator. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, along with restoring the simulator to default settings and restarting the simulator but the white screen bug persists.

But when running the app on my phone, pushing the view works as intended!

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) - Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-726.7)

Answer (score 0):

> It didn't used to do this.. but I haven't touched how the view is shown so not sure why it's doing it now.

You can use `git bisect` to find the change that caused this.